# How to change column display order mobile/tablet view CSS Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress event theme and on the single event page I want to show the left hand sidebar content above the main body copy in smaller/portrait viewports. The page in question is: http://staging.foxandmonkey.co.uk/event/brunch-808-uk-garage/

Here is the PHP the theme is pulling from:

```
global $tp_sidebar, $tp_content_class, $tp_title;
if ( $tp_sidebar ) {
$right_class = 'col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5';
$left_class = 'col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7';
}
else {
$right_class = 'col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4';
$left_class = 'col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8';
}
?>

<?php tribe_get_template_part( 'custom/wrapper-start' ); ?>

<div id="tribe-events-content" class="tribe-events-single vevent hentry">

<!-- Notices -->
<?php 
if ( function_exists('tribe_the_notices') ) {
    tribe_the_notices();
}
elseif ( function_exists('tribe_events_the_notices') ) {
    tribe_events_the_notices();
}
?>

<div class="events-single-right <?php echo esc_attr( $right_class ); ?>">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) :  the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <?php if ( !$tp_title ) : ?>
                <h2 class="entry-title">
                    <?php the_title() ?>
                </h2>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- Event featured image, but exclude link -->
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <div class="tribe-events-event-image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- Event content -->
<?php do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_before_the_content' ) ?>

<div class="tribe-events-single-event-description tribe-events-   content entry-content description">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- .tribe-events-single-event-description -->
            <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content' ) ?>

        </div> <!-- #post-x -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

<div class="events-single-left <?php echo esc_attr( $left_class ); ?>">

    <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'custom/cta' ); ?>

    <!-- Event meta -->
    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_before_the_meta' ) ?>

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_meta_primary_section_start' ); ?>

    <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'modules/meta/details' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_meta_primary_section_end' ); ?>

    <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'modules/meta/venue' ); ?>

    <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'modules/meta/map' ); ?>

    <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'custom/schedule' ); ?>

    <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'custom/custom' ); ?>

    <?php 
    // Include organizer meta if appropriate
    if ( tribe_has_organizer() ) {
        tribe_get_template_part( 'modules/meta/organizer' );
    } 
    ?>

    </div>
```

The page has no sidebar so I am assuming this part is what is defining the left and right content:

```
$right_class = 'col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4';
$left_class = 'col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8';
```

I am very new to CSS and Bootstrap so could you help me set some custom CSS to display the left calss before the right in mobile and portrait tablet view? Here is the CSS that is currently in the theme file:

```
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-single {
background: white;
margin: 0 0 30px;
padding: 50px;
}
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-single .events-single-left {
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-single .events-single-left {
min-height: 200px !important;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-single .events-single-left {
border-right: 1px solid #3ec9ce;
 }
}
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-single .events-single-right {
padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-single .events-single-right {
min-height: 200px !important;
 }
}
```

Thanks for any advice you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your left and right sections are being rendered backwards as the right section comes before the left in the HTML that is generated by your PHP page. The left and right classes (that you've correctly identified to be important) are then using some more advanced Bootstrap styles (those including push and pull) to essentially reorder the sections so that the left appears on the left and the right appears on the right. Pretty complicated!

To accomplish what you've asked, I recommend simplifying things a lot. Firstly, you need to change the order in the PHP page of the two sections. Take the right hand section, which is the div starting with `<div class="events-single-right" ...` and move it, along with its contents, below the left hand section (very bottom of your code sample in this case). This may illustrate the idea better:

Old structure:

```
(other code)

<div class="events-single-right <?php echo esc_attr( $right_class ); ?>">
    (right div contents)
</div>

<div class="events-single-left <?php echo esc_attr( $left_class ); ?>">
    (left div contents)
</div>
```

New structure:

```
(other code)

<div class="events-single-left <?php echo esc_attr( $left_class ); ?>">
    (left div contents)
</div>

<div class="events-single-right <?php echo esc_attr( $right_class ); ?>">
    (right div contents)
</div>
```

Essentially you're just swapping the two blocks around so the left section comes first, as this is logically what you want to achieve.

Once you've done that, fix those classes. Bootstrap's system is actually quite straightforward. They define 4 different screen sizes, mobile, tablet portrait/small, tablet landscape/large, and desktop. These correspond to the CSS classes `col-xs-...`, `col-sm-...`, `col-md-...`, and `col-lg-...`, respectively, at least for columns, which is what you're interested in.

Bootstrap then divides up the width of the container (in this case, your page width) into 12 invisible columns. You can then specify the width of your divs by giving the number of these columns you want to occupy in the CSS class. Specifying 12 means the div occupies the whole width, whereas specifying 6 means it occupies only half the width (6/12).

Putting this together, using `col-xs-6` instructs your div to take up half the width of the page (`-6`) when viewed on mobile screen sizes (`-xs`), whereas `col-sm-3` means your div takes up a quarter of the width on tablets in portrait orientation. You can combine multiple classes into one div, to specify how that div's width changes as the screen size increases.

Bootstrap is also designed to be 'mobile-first'. A consequence of this is that if you do not explicitly give a width for a div in a larger screen size, Bootstrap works backwards and assumes you want to keep the same div width (number of columns) as in smaller screen sizes. Additionally, divs essentially default to `col-xs-12` if you don't specify any classes, which combined with the rule above means that by default a div takes up the whole width (12 columns) across all screen sizes (the larger screen sizes all look down to mobile sizing and copy it).

Putting all that together, the classes you need are simply as follows:

```
$left_class = 'col-md-4';
$right_class = 'col-md-8';
```

This will make the left and right sections occupy the full width (and so come vertically above each other) on mobile and on portrait tablet (`xs` and `sm`) as we haven't explicitly specified any classes for these screen sizes and the default always starts at `col-xs-12`. We then specify `col-md-4` and `col-md-8`, which means that starting on landscape tablet screens, the sizing changes to make the left section take up 1/3 of the width and the right section 2/3 of the width. Desktop sizing then mimics these dimensions, as again it isn't explicitly specified.

If you wanted to alter things further such that only desktop screens used the two columns side-by-side, and on all other sizes left comes above right, just change those classes to `lg` instead of `md`.

I hope this makes things a bit clearer, and accomplishes what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Brilliant that worked perfectly and very clear explanation of how Bootstrap achieves column order!

Answer (score 0):

If you place the sidebar div before the main content div in the HTML, you won't need to use the Bootstrap pushes and pulls. Then as the viewport gets smaller, the sidebar will naturally come above the main content as that is the order they appear in the HTML.

So:

- Switch the order of the sidebar and content
- Remove the respective `col-sm-push-4` and `col-sm-pull-8` classes.